# cannot divide file into parts using partitionByInstrument

Tags: python, midi, music21

Using music21 cannot divide file into parts using `partitionByInstrument`.

```
from music21 import *

song = converter.parse("/Nottingham/train/ashover_simple_chords_12.mid")
print(len(song.parts)) # prints 2
parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(song)
print(parts.parts[0].id)
```

Shows fallowing error

```
print(parts.parts[0].id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parts'
```

Also when I check what song object contains `song.show("text")` I can see that there are parts. Raw paste [here](https://pastebin.com/xFJj0AkA).

This issue happens on all [Nottingham midi dataset](http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~boulanni/icml2012). When I tried on different midi files everything was okay and `partitionByInstrument` worked as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleInstrument.html#music21.instrument.partitionByInstrument) says:

> partition into a Part for each unique Instrument

But this file does not specify any instrument, so there is no partition to put the data into. In this case, `partitionByInstrument()` apparently returns `None`.